# Post Rig modeling/object question

Tags: modeling, rigging

I recently rigged a character that is a single object, with no parts. Just one mesh. The rigging is fine and works, but when I move the Master controller everything moves with it, except the teeth and the pupils. Is there a reason why they would be separate? I made sure there was no odd weight texture on it (I think) but can't figure out why the teeth and pupils don't move, as if they were totally separate. And they don't deform. They just sit there.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: they must not have been affected to any bone, you need to select these parts and assign them to the Vertex Group they are supposed to be part of

Comment: At this point, the only separation is that they are different textures. But still the same object. How could it not be affected? And I did weight paint them in to a bone controller, so can't figure out why it wouldn't touch them.